# Xamarin app connection to MongoDB - DnsClientWrapper throwing exception

Tags: c#, mongodb, forms, xamarin

I'm creating an Android app using Xamarin Forms and C# which should contact a MongoDB Atlas cloud service. I am using the MongoDB driver v 2.17.1 and deploying to Android v12 (Samsung S21).

When attempting a to build a MongoClientSettings using the connection string copied from the Atlas server I get the following exception...

> [0:] The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper' threw an exception.
> [0:]   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionString..ctor (System.String connectionString) [0x00000] in <4ae800ad3ec4467cb63945849677f181>:0
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrlBuilder.Parse (System.String url) [0x00000] in <9ac288b7382b43efae8d31b0427527db>:0
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrlBuilder..ctor (System.String url) [0x00006] in <9ac288b7382b43efae8d31b0427527db>:0
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl..ctor (System.String url) [0x00000] in <9ac288b7382b43efae8d31b0427527db>:0
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString (System.String connectionString) [0x00000] in <9ac288b7382b43efae8d31b0427527db>:0
> at CarbCounter.Services.MongoDataStore.SetupConnection () [0x00002] in C:\Visual Studio\CarbCounter\CarbCounter\CarbCounter\Services\MongoDataStore.cs:51

Code is:

**MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);

settings.ServerApi = new ServerApi(ServerApiVersion.V1);

settings.LinqProvider = LinqProvider.V3;**

The same code runs fine when built in a prototype Windows console app.

I've tried updating DnsClient (which the above class wraps)... no effect.
I've tried rolling back the MongoDB driver to v2.73 and using slightly different code (no ServerAPI or LinqProvider settings, slightly different connection string again provided by the Atlas server), this caused a different exception from the same line of code whereby the OS was unable to resolve the DNS of the server.

Any ideas? I'm about to give up with Mongo and try a different DB.

Comment: what does your connectiontstring look like?

Comment: `DnsClientWrapper` uses a third party lib named `DnsClient`. Does it support Android?

Comment: Connection string is the one provided by the atlas server... mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<apname>.wy1rmxy.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: I think that you're right @Markus. The website says it supports Win, Mac, Linux.  I guess that does for using MongoDB in a Xamarin Android ap then.   Thanks for the response.